# Leaflet-pip - Display properties of overlays polygons

Tags: leaflet, point-in-polygon

I'm using [leaflet-pip](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-pip) to return overlays polygon in a clicked point. Results seems to be good, but I have an array with `[object Object]`. How can I display the name or specific properties of matched features ?

For example

```
var myLayer = L.geoJson(myData,{
}).addTo(map);

var match = leafletPip.pointInLayer([-0.993005, 49.069792], myLayer, false);

alert(match);
```

Data

```
var myData = 
{"type": 'FeatureCollection", "features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": "01", "type": "type01" ...
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": "02", "type": "type02" ...
]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access to the feature properties, it should be:

```
if (match.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < match.length; i++) { 
        name = match[i].feature.properties.name;
        type = match[i].feature.properties.type;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then you can pass the properties to a popup:

```
var popup = L.popup()
    .setLatLng([lat, lon])
    .setContent("<b>Name:</b> " + name + "<br><b>Type:</b> " + type)
    .openOn(map);
```

where `[lat, lon]` are the coordinates of the clicked point.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.